# What version of JBoss I am running?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

(As asked in title:) How do I tell what version of JBoss I am running?

I am also curious what version of tomcat I am running. Does a specific version of JBoss correspond to a certain version of tomcat?

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude I updated my post, which version of JBoss are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JBoss has an MBean called Server. That reports the build and version of JBoss itself. Once you know the version, you can see what components are involved. It is not that well cataloged, but you can see it in the release notes.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude, stacker provided the exact URL. It is visible on the jmx-console and the web-console (http://[jbossurl]:[jbossport]/jmx-console/ (or /web-console).

Answer (score 16):

In your JBoss lib Directory:

- Open the file **jboss-system.jar** by example
- Extract the file MANIFEST.MF from the **META-INF** directory
- Open **MANIFEST.MF** with a text editor and then look at the property **Specification-Version** and **Implementation-Version**

Comment: ```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.5
Created-By: 1.8.0_231-b11 (Oracle Corporation)
```
I get this message from the file. Is the version mentioned after  "Created-by"?

Answer (score 13):

This URL (JMX-Console) should provide you the informations

`http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=inspectMBean&name=jboss.system%3Atype%3DServer`

The tomcat version is implied by the jboss server version.

EDIT:

A complete list of versions you find here [VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS)

Where you reach your JBoss depends on the interface it is bound, using -b **hostname**
If you start using JBoss with -b 0.0.0.0 option. That way, you can access the system using localhost, machineName and even the IP address. 
By default it's localhost, if you use th -b option you need to replace **localhost** by **yourhostname**.

Comment: +1: for tomcat info.  But getting a `unable to connect` from that url.

Comment: Does that mean the MBean Server is not there...?

Comment: should MBean server be in the jboss-service?

Answer (score 10):

Just found another way to know the **jboss version**, so pointing out here:

In `Linux`/`Windows` use `--version` parameter along with **Jboss executable** to know the Jboss Version

eg:

```
[immo@g012 bin]$  ./run.sh --version
========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /programs/jboss4.2-AES2.3Cert

  JAVA: /programs/java/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS: -server -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 

  CLASSPATH: /programs/jboss4.2-AES2.3Cert/bin/run.jar:/programs/java/jdk1.7.0_09/lib/tools.jar

=========================================================================

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
JBoss 4.0.4.GA (build: CVSTag=JBoss_4_0_4_GA date=200605151000)
```

Here `JBoss 4.0.4.GA` is the Jboss version

in windows this could be

```
run.bat --version
```

Also, in new versions of jboss the executable is `standalone.sh` / `standalone.bat`

Answer (score 6):

Realize this is an old thread but here are a couple other ways (works with EAP  6.4):

1. Use JBoss CLI (/opt/jboss/bin)

`# jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=127.0.0.1:9999 'version'
JBoss Admin Command-line Interface
JBOSS_HOME: /opt/AAS/latest/jboss
JBoss AS release: 7.5.14.Final-redhat-2 "Janus"
JBoss AS product: EAP 6.4.14.GA`

2. Inspect the identity.conf file

`# more /opt/jboss/.installation/identity.conf
patches=
cumulative-patch-id=jboss-eap-6.4.14.CP
installed-patches=jboss-eap-6.4.1.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.2.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.3.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.4.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.5.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.6.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.7.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.8.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.9.CP,
jboss-eap-6.4.10.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.11.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.12.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.13.CP,jboss-eap-6.4.14.CP`

Answer (score 4):

```
/apps/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/standalone.sh -version
```

Sample output:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /apps/jboss-eap-6.2

  JAVA: /apps/jdks/jdk_1.7/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

21:07:20,380 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final-redhat-1
21:07:22,206 INFO  [stdout] (main) JBoss EAP 6.2.2.GA (AS 7.3.2.Final-redhat-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps there is also a `jar-versions.xml` in my JBoss installation in JBoss root folder. This doesn't require you to `wget` or `jar xvf`.

E.g.

```
$  grep jboss-system.jar /opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/jar-versions.xml | fold
  <jar name="jboss-system.jar" specVersion="5.1.0.GA" specVendor="JBoss (http://
www.jboss.org/)" specTitle="JBoss" implVersion="5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_
1_0_GA date=200905221634)" implVendor="JBoss Inc." implTitle="JBoss [The Oracle]
" implVendorID="http://www.jboss.org/" implURL="http://www.jboss.org/" sealed="f
alse" md5Digest="c97e8a3dde7433b6c26d723413e17dbc"/>
$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the location of installed jboss folder then simply open it and look for `version.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve information about the version of your JBoss EAP installation by running the same script used to start the server with the -V switch. For Linux and Unix installations this script is run.sh and on Microsoft Windows installations it is run.bat. Regardless of platform the script is located in $JBOSS_HOME/bin. Using these scripts to actually start your server is dealt with in Chapter 4, Launching the JBoss EAP Server.

Answer (score 0):

The version of JBoss should also be visible in the boot log file. Standard install would have that (for linux) in

/var/log/jboss/boot.log

$ head boot.log

```
08:30:07,477 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...
08:30:07,478 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)
08:30:07,478 DEBUG [Server] Using config: org.jboss.system.server.ServerConfigImpl@4277158a
08:30:07,478 DEBUG [Server] Server type: class org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl
08:30:07,478 DEBUG [Server] Server loaded through: org.jboss.system.server.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader
08:30:07,478 DEBUG [Server] Boot URLs:
```

so required info int the above case is

Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command from Linux

```
find $JBOSS_HOME -name run.sh -exec {} -V \; | grep '^JBoss'
```

Answer (score 0):

Redhat recommended way of getting the Jboss EAP version using HTTP management :

```
http://localhost:9990/management?operation=attribute&name=product-version
```

This URL will return the exact Jboss version.

Or else version can also be retrieved using the below java code :

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

@Singleton
public class JBossServerVersionBean {

    private MBeanServer server;
    private String serverName;
    private String serverVersion;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

        try {
            ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("jboss.as:management-root=server");

            serverName = (String) server.getAttribute(objectName, "productName");
            serverVersion = (String) server.getAttribute(objectName, "productVersion");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to obtain server name and version!", e);
        }
    }

    public String getJBossServerName() {
        return serverName;
    }

    public String getJBossServerVersion() {
        return serverVersion;
    }
}
```