# how to check JBOSS version using ANT script

Tags: java, ant, jboss

I have written ant script to check for java version. Similarly I would like to know how to check for JBOSS version using ant script.

```
  <project basedir="." default="check-java-version">
  <target name="get-java-version">
  <echo message="Java Version: ${java.version}"/> 
    <echo message="Java home: ${java.home}"/> 
    <fail message="Unsupported Java version: ${java.version}. Make sure that  
     the version of the Java compiler is 1.7 or greater."> 
        <condition> 
            <not> 
                <or> 
                    <contains string="${java.version}" substring="1.7" casesensitive="false" />                         
                     <contains string="${java.version}" substring="1.8" casesensitive="false" /> 
                </or>                       
            </not> 
        </condition> 
    </fail> 
  </target>
  <target name="check-java-version" depends="get-java-version"              
  unless="java.version">

   </target>
 </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to do this from the same box where jboss is installed you can try the exec task on "standalone.bat --version" or the "run.sh --version"

if you want to query a remote JBOSS instance you can execute curl against 
http://yourserver:port/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=inspectMBean&name=jboss.system%3Atype%3DServer

you can also check: [What version of JBoss I am running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335275/what-version-of-jboss-i-am-running) for how to derive it from the jar.

-- Adding a sample on how to implement this in Ant:

```
<exec dir="${yourJbossDir}" executable="run.sh" outputproperty="JbossVersion">
   <arg line="--version"/>
</exec>
```

then you would get the vesrsion stored in the JbossVersion property.
see also:  https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply.the question is to check jboss version in ant script.